# how to pick image from webview in android

Tags: android, image, webview

I work upon Image Base64 encode/decode application. so i want to pick image from google image in webview and convert into Base64 string.

```
so how i can pick image on touch event in webview.
```

Thanks in advance. [image]

[image]

Comment: by "pick" do you mean selecting an image?

Comment: @alice sometime ago i was facing the similar issue, haven't found solution yet. For e.g. lets take above problem , **Open webview** -> **search on google** -> **search for "car" in google-images** -> **click on any image from list of images appeared** -> **Shows similar layout shown in second screenshot (gallery kind of layout)** -> **when pressed on any image so how to fetch image source or url from here**. As when i was working on this, page was not providing any url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the html content from webiview, and get the image that is in tags

Comment: I am getting all urls and not able to get which image has been clicked. See Screenshot 2 above, it is kind of gallery-view. So it is not providing me any id or specific url. Or if you have any idea plz reply here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try... `HTTPRequest`
Split all image tag.
Get each url.

You will get all url of image

Comment: I don't want all urls rather i want a specific url of image which has been clicked by user. Look i have a problem at screenshot 2, when first screenshot gets load, i think all images are getting loaded in cache,  even i am getting all urls as well using webview but when i redirected to screenshot 2 from first, it is not providing me any url or id, which image has been clicked or any reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use a webview with a custom WebViewClient, and override the onLoadResource to capture the image loading.

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url) 
{
    // debug the page to get the URL format then create filter for images
    // capture image URL here 
}
```

After you got the needed URL, convert the URL to a bitmap
sample function:
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {

```
    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        //TODO on error
        return null;
    }
}
```